# Changing font style while keeping external stylesheet for plotly dashboard

Tags: python, css, plotly, plotly-dash

I build up a dashboard using dash and plotly while using the reference to the external stylsheet that is used in [every tutorial or documentation for dash and plotly](https://dash.plot.ly/getting-started).

Now I want to customize just the font for the whole dashboard (including text in figures) and "nothing else". I'm referencing to the external css source via:

```
external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']
```

I have no CSS experience. Can I just overwrite the relevant variables from within the referenced source? If it is possible, how do I do it? Like:

```
font-family: "Garamond";
```

The CSS code is published on codepen and I tried to search there as well, but I wasn't helpful.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the universal CSS selector `*`.

Create `/assets/custom.css` in your app directory, or (what I do) create a CodePen with your custom CSS and include it first in the list of `external_stylesheets` in

```
app = dash.Dash(
    __name__,
    external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets
)
```

---

In `assets/custom.css` or CodePen:

```
*{
  font-family: Garamond;
}
```

If you want to apply it to everything except certain classes element/component types, e.g. "everything except `h2` and class `myclass`"

```
*:not(h2):not(.myclass){
  font-family: Garamond;
}
```

Comment: Hey @russellr, I'm sure this is answering my question. Can you elaborate a bit more on how to customize the CSS on CodePen. So I should copy the content of the referenced CSS, creaty my own Pen, copy the content into it and adding your second code snippet right at the top. Am I correct? :)

Comment: Basically. Try it out. Reference the codepen with the URL plus `.css` in external stylesheets like in chriddyp's examples.

Comment: how is this possible without CodePen? just creating a file custom.css in the assets folder appears to have no effect

Comment: Any CSS file should automatically be included as long as you do `app = dash.Dash(__name__)`. See https://dash.plot.ly/external-resources